# Is there an R function to take the derivative every 4th dy value?

Tags: r

I am a fairly new programmer in R and have this time sequence data that only receives data hourly from the equipment in the field. This is just a snippet from the large data file I have, but I am trying to compute the derivatives in R. X= AI (index) and Y= soiltotal. I am looking for the code that allows me to take the derivative every 4th soiltotal value without the data getting out of sync according to the index in R. I cannot make changes to the index column.

[image: from the excel file]

I have tried many things but since there are missing values R puts NA for the entire column of derivatives.

I have tried this code:

```
# Sample data
x <- verett`AI`
y <- verett`soiltotal`


# Derivative values
dy_dx <- c(NA, diff(y) / diff(x))  # Add NA for the first entry

# Add the derivative values as a new column
verett`DST` <- dy_dx
```

I also tried using `seq(from, to, 4)`

Comment: Welcome to SO, sloanp10! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Some thoughts: (1) If you don't need the 3 (out of 4) empty rows, you can filter with `x[complete.cases(x),]` (assuming all other fields should be non-empty), after which all analysis should be able to continue without change. This means your `AI` values will be `c(3, 7, 11, 15, ...)`. (2) If instead you _need_ the `AI` value to retain `0:31` (in this example), then you may want to impute the missing values, either last-observation carried forward (LOCF), mean, sampled, or some other imputation mechanisms.

Comment: When you [edit] your question to provide usable data (and perhaps whatever code you've already tried), please also add (via. `data.frame` or similar) ideally what your expected output should be given these missing values. Thanks!